# Dissolving neighbors polygons by specific field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve, proximity, aggregation

I have a polygon layer and I want to dissolve the polygons according to a specific field. I would like to dissolve only the neighbors polygons. For example, look at the below image.

I would like the marked polygons with a red pen to be different features.

[image]

Is there any possible way? I use QGIS but any answer in ArcGIS is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polygons you want to dissolve are few, then you can merge them manually using the ["Merge selected features"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=advanced#merge-selected-features) tool, as you can see below:

[image]

Start editing → Select the polygon you want to merge → it will prompt you a table to choose which field you want to use. Then select that feature and click <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

ArcGIS has the same tool. Go to Editor → Start editing → Select the polygons you want to merge → Go to editor and select Merge.

Right-click the toolbar panel and Select `Advanced Digitizing toolbar`, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: what is the name of the plugin you use?

Comment: It is not Plugin, it comes with QGIS. I am using QGIS 2.14.7. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to run the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) function after dissolving. Features that do not touch should become singleparts.